# Wordpress Rest API custom field not updating till i manually update the post

Tags: custom-field, api

i m using a video theme, i have two custom fields called, actor and add new actor.
if i add new actor , it automatically create a actor. and the name i put on 'new actor' field shows on 'actor' field after publishing.

i use rest api to make posts. problem is i have to manually update the post to add the name to 'actor' field.[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd guess this is because the actor field for the UI is being dynamically calculated from linked actors somehow, and the REST API isn't using the same logic. But I don't know exactly how that would work. The REST API can almost certainly be set up to do this too, or the 'new actor' code set up to update the meta field in a way that the REST API can read. I'd talk to whoever wrote your video theme for help.

Comment: thank you for the comment , i ll contact the theme writer